# Deleting Document Tabs in DocuSign Through the APIs

Tags: javascript, docusignapi, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm adjusting an integration with DocuSign in NetSuite to delete certain tabs in a document based on user selection so that when the signatory receives the document to sign, there aren't empty tabs to be filled out that don't apply to the situation and cause confusion. However, it seems rather unclear as to how that is to be accomplished. I've looked at the documentation for what appears to be the necessary API endpoint here:

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocumenttabs/delete/

It indicates a call using the DELETE verb, but also seems to say that POST data is to be included, even though POST data with a DELETE call isn't supported in SuiteScript (or most platforms overall).

Would I be better off trying to do an update on the selected tabs, instead? Using a PUT to that endpoint and try to either lock, hide, and/or shrink these tabs?

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocumenttabs/update/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would actually recommend to use https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipienttabs/update/ if you have the **recipientId** for the specific recipient that you want to delete tabs for.
And when using this, you have to specify the tabs you want, even these you didn't delete. Essentially you're overriding the list of tabs for this recipient.

Note that the DEL endpoint for tabs delete all tabs, not just a specific tab so that won't do what you need.

Comment: Ah, ok. That's good to know. Explains the documentation a bit, given that they did not mention it from what I could see. What would be the recommended metadata for the tabs to be "removed", then? Lock them? Reduce height and width to zero? Both? Something else?

Comment: you just don't include them, no data or meta-data. You just include all the tabs you WANT to have, you don't say what you want to be removed, you just remove it.

Comment: Ah! Excellent. Thank you. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: This seems to get me where I need to be with this, along with some creative editing before sending the initial document creation request. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely our bug. DELETE endpoints shouldn't have request bodies.

We'll get it cleaned up as soon as we can. Thanks for letting us know.